# Blender restarts audio, makes it impossible to edit

Tags: animation, rigging, edit-mode, audio

For some reason I can't edit my audio in blender. I'm trying to match it up to my animation but whenever I press play blender plays it from the start, regardless of where my playhead is. It's also ignoring my edits and the displayed waveform is not matching the audio at all.

I didn't make the mesh/rig I'm animating, just a free blend file. But I've figure out that if I delete every Sphere object that says "polystrips" the problem is solved, but I don't know why. And the issue is that  those spheres are essential.

I'm kinda freaking out the deadline for my animation is in a month and I can't show it without synced audio, any help with fixing this would be highly appreciated.

Blend.File: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1mQpDUJYU1UYeLGNgBs5SGRiSLNEgi7cW

Audio: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Fda7hRBjlqFI7EMsK5eLSbR7gL-WCPmQ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Could you post what version of Blender you are using and system info?

I downloaded both files, and the audio is synced fine when I import it / move it in the VSE.

Comment: Blender 2.81a, on macOs Mojave 10.14.4. When you say the audio is synced up can you play the audio pause and then press play again without it skipping back and re-playing the audio? Can you make edits by cutting the strip and rearrange it, cause that doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: Yup, the audio will adjust itself live if I drag it while also playing the animation. I'm also able to make those edits that you mentioned. Try updating to the newest stable release  2.82, that may solve your issue. I'm using 2.82.7 on Win10.

Comment: I just did 2.82a still the same problem, here's a video to show it (sound on)  https://drive.google.com/open?id=1VUc6yJinrmUdR2kvSIZftNwGYyDqFr8x

Comment: Pausing and playing on my end is working properly...it sounds like a bug that should be reported to *developer.blender.org*. What you may want to do is rendering the animation to an image sequence, then converting that image sequence into a video file so you can then use a different video editor to put the audio and video together.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I've reported it now, hopefully there is a fix